# Postgresql: read the content of file and insert in to Column throws 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: postgresql, powershell, psql, postgresql-14

i have 2 files. 1) is `txt.sql` and 2) is `post.html` . i am try to insert in to my postgresql Table using .sql script. used windows cmd, Powershell and my IDE(vscode as well).

my script code here **txt.sql**

```
\set content `cat post.html`
INSERT INTO posts (
    post_name,
    post_date,
    title,
    body
)
VALUES(
    'hello_world',
    '2021-12-20',
    'Hello World',
    :'content'
);
```

and my **post.html** code here

```
<h1>
    Hello World!
</h1>
<p>
    Thank you for visiting my blog.
</p>
```

when i ran below command against `myapp` database.

```
myapp-# \i txt.sql
```

got below results and inserted data with out content

> 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> INSERT 0 1

i belive `cat` shell command only for unix and not for windows.
can you help me with other solution to read data from file and insert in to table column in windows psql.

Comment: The prompt `myapp-#` suggests that you are on a continuation line. Try again.

Comment: yes, but body field value is not inserted. that's the problem. i want to insert value for body field from content of file

Comment: Your sample code works perfectly. The problem is that you are in the middle of a statement. Disconnect from the database, reconnect, and it will work.

Comment: tried, but body is not gonna inserted, i think bacuase mine is windows machine? @ 
Laurenz Albe is any working example?

Comment: Your sample works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows equivalent of `cat` is called `type`.

From the [horse's mouth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type):

> `type` is a built in command which displays the contents of a text file.